# I try to execute reg query in cygwin but it shows me following error

Tags: shell

ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value

please any one help me solve this error.
basically i want to redirect this error to /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to replace single backslashes `\` with double backslashes `\\` since your shell is probably eating one of them.